# Variable is not defined in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I have this error on React: 
`./src/App.js
  Line 44:  'newQuantityById' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 45:  'newQuantityById' is not defined  no-undef`

it's about a code from a function and newQuantityById is const

```
`removeFromCart = (id) => {
    const {addedIds,quantityById} = this.state;
    if(quantityById[id]){
      const newQuantitById = {
        ...quantityById,
        [id]: quantityById[id] > 1 ? quantityById[id] - 1 : undefined
      }
      const newAddedIds = newQuantityById[id] ? addedIds : addedIds.filter(prodId => prodId !== id); //Line 44 Error
      this.setState({addedIds: newAddedIds, quantityById: newQuantityById}); //Line 45 Error
    }
  }`
```

Comment: You spelled `newQuantityById` wrong when you defined it (missing the `y`)

Answer (score 3):

You got a typo here:

```
const newQuantitById = {
               ^^
```

You missed `..tit(->y<-)ById`.

Comment: You did a great Catch!!!!

Comment: Thank you. :) @ma_dev_15

Comment: Oh I've just seen it now, thank you. What a mistake XD